# My app crash when enter in landscape mode, ConcurrentModificationException using coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, arraylist, kotlin-coroutines

I've created a landscape variation of my portrait layout with all views that are contained in my layout.

But when I run the app and rotate the device there is a crash with this error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: DefaultDispatcher-worker-1
    Process: com.user.project_name, PID: 15543
    java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:860)
        at com.user.project_name.MainActivity$findSingleCountry$1.invokeSuspend(MainActivity.kt:157)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:106)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler.runSafely(CoroutineScheduler.kt:571)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.executeTask(CoroutineScheduler.kt:750)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.runWorker(CoroutineScheduler.kt:678)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.scheduling.CoroutineScheduler$Worker.run(CoroutineScheduler.kt:665)
```

This error refer to this code on my MainActivity:

```
private fun findSingleCountry(name: String) {
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
        fiscalCode.birthPlace = "X999"
        for (country in countryList) {
            if (country.description.uppercase() == name.uppercase()) {
                fiscalCode.birthPlace = country.code
                break
            }
        }
        cFViewModel.getFiscalCode(fiscalCode)
    }
}
```

The line 157 is: `for (country in countryList) {`

I call this method only in my onCreate() with:

```
    binding.acBirthCountry.setOnItemClickListener { adapterView, _, itemPos, _ ->
        fiscalCode.birthPlace =  (adapterView.adapter.getItem(itemPos) as CountryModel).code
        cFViewModel.getFiscalCode(fiscalCode)
    }
    binding.acBirthCountry.doAfterTextChanged { name ->
        findSingleCountry(name.toString())
    }
```

Why did this crash my app only when it enters the landscape mode?

**Edit:**

How can I resolve this problem without run the function in the Main thread?

**Edit:**

According to [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException):

> Note that this exception does not always indicate that an object has been concurrently modified by a different thread. If a single thread issues a sequence of method invocations that violates the contract of an object, the object may throw this exception. For example, if a thread modifies a collection directly while it is iterating over the collection with a fail-fast iterator, the iterator will throw this exception.

This exception is only an alert that the code could **violates the contract of an object**, in fact when the device switch to landscape mode the method `findSingleCountry` is not called.

It is the case to ignore the exception when I enter in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

The issue most likely lies in the fact that the collection `countryList` is modified (probably just recreated) by the `Main` thread and the other thread (in your case `Default`) iterates over that collection. You can take a look at the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException) on the `ConcurrentModificationException`:

> This exception may be thrown by methods that have detected concurrent modification of an object when such modification is not permissible.

> For example, it is not generally permissible for one thread to modify a Collection while another thread is iterating over it. In general, the results of the iteration are undefined under these circumstances.

Knowing that the `Main` thread is the one that the `onCreate` method operates on, I think that changing the thread dispatcher would help. Try changing Your code like this:

```kotlin
CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Main).launch {
   ...
}
```

Edit:

The function `findSingleCountry` is probably executed only in the `onCreate` method, so I think that **taking the code out of the `CoroutineScope` would be actually more helpful**.

Comment: This resolves the error, but it isn't best practice to execute this block code in the Main thread because the computational cost depends on a list length. If the list contains thousands of entries this will be critical to executing in the Main thread. That is because I need to run on the Default pool thread

Comment: Hmmm, good point. In that case I would consider moving the code to the `onStart` callback method. Also, if the answer resolved the error You can mark it as accepted or upvote.